# Sort by list of terms first with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I got an ecommerce site where i list products. The list can be sorted by name, brand or price.

Now i want to offer a feature where users can define a list of preferred brands. Those brands should show on top of the list first, independent of the other sort parameter. Example user prefers 'SRAM' and 'Shimano' brands. An example sorted query by price would look like this:

```
<Brand>   <Price(desc)>
SRAM      99.00
Shimano   95.00
SRAM      87.50
SRAM      67.90
Shimano   59.90
AVID      125.90
RaceFace  115.90
ENVE      70.00
RaceFace  63.60
```

I understand that i can have multilevel sorting. I assumed this is a sorting problem and not another feature. So i'm looking for a sort where being part of a list of terms would show first, then second level i can use sort by price which i already got working. Can anyone point me to what this is called what i'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight)

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": { "match_all": {} },
          "boost": "5", 
          "functions": [
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "BRAND": "Sram" } },
                  "weight": 2
              },
              {
                  "filter": { "match": { "BRAND": "shimano" } },
                  "weight": 3
              }
          ],
          "score_mode": "max",
          "boost_mode": "multiply",
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this clearly is the way to do it. Can i just use my existing query in the 'function_score' wrapper?

Comment: @JanDetlefsen Sure you can do that

Comment: @JanDetlefsen But there is probably the the trick that to boost documents they must be returned by query. I mean that for instance if you query is to filter by brand: "stackoverflow" but you are boosting sram and shimano they will probably be not returned at all since basic query filters them. But this you should try :)